# [React-Native-Firebase]How can i remove onMessage exist event?

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I declare a onMessage function with do something. But when i navigate to another screen and want to remove FCM.onMessage() in ComponentWillUnmount(). How can i remove that?

```
const rnfirebase = RNFirebase.initializeApp()

export const FCM = rnfirebase.messaging()

ComponentDidMount(){
    FCM.onMessage((notif)=>{

        //Do something

    })

}
ComponentWillUnmount(){
    //I want to remove here

}
```

Comment: can you please share more where this function is written by you mean to say file and default function?

Comment: I just Updated code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you check the [docs](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.2.x/messaging/reference/messaging#onMessage) the onMessage returns a function and if console log that function you will see something like this

```
ƒ () {
    return rnListener.remove();
  }
```

so when you call the function returned by onMessage it will stop listening and in your case, the code will look like this

```
const rnfirebase = RNFirebase.initializeApp()

export const FCM = rnfirebase.messaging()

componentDidMount(){
    this.notificationListener = FCM.onMessage(notif=>{
        //Do something
    })
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    this.notificationListener(); //This will remove the listener
}
```

Comment: although it's not recommend to just to say thks here,   I need to say ... that solve my day! Thank you!